# Vertically scrollable Gantt type charts in Streamlit / Altair

Tags: python, streamlit, altair

I am trying to generate equipment occupancy charts using Streamlit & Altair.
These are similar to Gantt charts, but each row is an equipment item, instead of a task, and there can be multiple bars on any given row.

When I produce a chart, it seems to expand to fit the horizontal width of the browser fine, but does not do so vertically. It produces a tall chart that is chopped, so that I have to scroll down to the bottom to see the x-axis.

I'd like to accomplish the following, but can't figure out how to do it:

- have the x and y axis visible at all times (not currently working)
- y axis should be vertically scrollable

  - It currently scrolls as if the chart is a very tall object that doesn't fit in the window, so x axis is only visible when I scroll to the bottom, i.e. it scrolls "external" to the chart in the vertical direction, in contrast to it scrolling within the chart in the horizontal direction.
- y axis should not be zoomable (this is working)
- x axis should be horizontally zoomable and pannable (this is working)

The following code produces a plot as per the image below.

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st

st.set_page_config(layout="wide")

def streamlit_plot(dataframe: pd.DataFrame, rooms: pd.Series) -> int:
    """Plot using streamlit."""
    with st.sidebar:
        selected_rooms = st.multiselect("Rooms", rooms, rooms)
        filtered_dataframe = dataframe[dataframe["Room"].isin(selected_rooms)]

    with st.empty():
        alt_chart = (
            alt.Chart(filtered_dataframe, height=800)
            .mark_bar()
            .mark_bar(height=20)
            .encode(
                x="Start DateTime",
                x2="Finish DateTime",
                y="Equipment",
                tooltip=["Annotation"],
            )
            .interactive()
            .properties(height=alt.Step(30))
            .configure_axis(grid=True)
        )
        st.altair_chart(alt_chart, use_container_width=True)

    return 0
```

In terms of input data:

- `rooms` is a pandas series of string identifiers for rooms (you can see them in the sidebar).
- `dataframe` is the main data being plotted, it consists of a few thousand rows, each representing an individual use of a piece of equipment.

[image: Chart with x axis not visible]

My current workaround is to render fewer bars as follows:

- Use an st.number_input widget to get a value for the max no. of bars to render (integer)
- Use an st.number_input widget to get a value for start position (integer)
- Generate a list of equipment, `trimmed_equipment`,  to render based on the above
- Slice the data in filtered_dataframe using `trimmed_dataframe = filtered_dataframe[filtered_dataframe["Equipment"].isin(trimmed_equipment)]`
- Plot the sliced data

```
filtered_equipment = list(filtered_dataframe["Equipment"].unique())
filtered_equipment_count = len(filtered_equipment)
st.text(f"{filtered_equipment_count} equipment tags in filtered data.")
max_rows = st.number_input("max rows to render", 1, None, 16)
if filtered_equipment_count > 1:
    start_row = st.number_input("start row", 1, filtered_equipment_count, 1)
else:
    start_row = 1
stop_row = min(start_row + max_rows, len(filtered_equipment))
try:
    trimmed_equipment = filtered_equipment[start_row - 1 : stop_row - 1]
except: # Trying to catch bad slices - TODO: More specific condition
    trimmed_equipment = filtered_equipment
trimmed_dataframe = filtered_dataframe[
    filtered_dataframe["Equipment"].isin(trimmed_equipment)
]
```